# How can I use ComponentName.js instead of index.js when importing React component (from Atomic design structure directory)

Tags: reactjs, components, gatsby, atomic-design

I am using [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org) (React) for my project. I am using [Atomic design](http://bradfrost.com/blog/post/atomic-web-design/) folder structure e.g:

```
src/components/Organisms/Header
```

In this folder I like to have:

```
src/components/Organisms/Header/header.js
src/components/Organisms/Header/header.module.scss
```

How can I import `header.js` from within `src/components/layout.js` like:

```
import Header from '@components/Organisms/Header'
```

instead of:

```
import Header from '@components/Organisms/Header/header'
```

**Update:**

I managed to do it by:

- adding an `index.js` file to `src/components/Organisms/Header/`
- and `export { default } from './header';` in `index.js`

But are this best practices?

Comment: In order to do this, you could create an `index.js` file which exports your `header` module as default.

Comment: @vjarysta Ok but how exactly? Are this best practices or **1** do I have to stick with naming them `index.js` or **2** when importing the components use `import Header from '@components/Organisms/Header/header'`

Comment: If you only have the `header` module to export, you should rename it to `index.js` directly.
If you have move than one module, you could use named exports, to avoid code repetition like `import Header from '@components/Organisms/Header/header'`; then you could `import { Header } from '@components/Organisms/Header'`.

Comment: if you're married to this folder structure, check out [directory named plugin for webpack](https://github.com/shaketbaby/directory-named-webpack-plugin). It'll resolve `/components/foo` to `/component/foo/foo.js`

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options here. With all of these you would import `src/components/Header`.

### 1. Flat with no component directory (my preference):

```
src
└── components
    ├── Header.js
    └── header.module.css
```

**Benefits**

- Less meaningless nesting
- No conflicting/confusing filenames open in your editor (e.g. index)
- Easy to follow the imports and exports

**Drawbacks**

- Nowhere for one-off resources and sub-components to go

---

### 2. Adjacent component and resources-directory (Ruby-style):

```
src
└── components
    ├── Header
    │   ├── header.module.css
    │   └── logo.png
    └── Header.js
```

**Benefits**

- Resources and sub-components are kept together
- No conflicting/confusing filenames open in your editor (e.g. index)
- Easy to follow the imports and exports

**Drawbacks**

- The component isn't adjacent to resources, so imports require a `./Header/` prefix
- Depending on the sorting, the resources directory may not be listed immediately adjacent to the component

---

### 3. With a directory index that exports `Header`:

```
src
└── components
    └── Header
        ├── Header.js
        ├── header.module.css
        ├── index.js
        └── logo.png
```

**Benefits**

- Component and resources are kept together
- Sorting doesn't matter

**Drawbacks**

- Conflicting/confusing filenames open in your editor (e.g. index)
- Confusing imports and exports, may cause hard-to-diagnose errors
- Extra work for every component

Comment: I'm looking for number 4. The perfect solution! :P